# No me crea el formulario - Django

Tags: python, django

No me carga el formulario en la página, no me marca error, pero en los `views` no me detecta el `httpResponse`, me aparece un mensaje que dice `"unused import statement"`. Ya he probado de todo y no lo carga. Cabe mencionar que le agregué un archivo de `Bootstrap` a a la aplicación, el cual si lo corre, pero al mandar el formulario no me lo crea.

El codigo views.py es este :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import  HttpResponse
from apps.paciente.forms import pacienteForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'paciente/index.html')

def paciente_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = pacienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('paciente:index')
        else:
            form = pacienteForm()
            return render(request, 'paciente/paciente_form.html',{'form':form})
```

El código del archivo de las `urls` es `urls.py` es este:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from apps.paciente.views import index, paciente_view

urlpatterns = [
  url('$', index, name='index'),
  url('nuevo$', paciente_view, name='paciente_crear'),
]
```

El de `forms.py` es este:

```
from django import forms
from .models import paciente

class pacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = paciente
        fields = [
          'nombre',
          'apellidoMaterno',
          'apellidoPaterno',
          'TipoDeSangre',
          'FechaDeNacimiento',
          'sexo',
          'edad',
        ]
        labels = {
          'nombre': 'Nombre',
          'apellidoMaterno': 'Apellido Materno',
          'apellidoPaterno ': 'Apellido Paterno',
          'TipoDeSangre ': 'Tipo de Sangre',
          'FechaDeNacimiento': 'Fecha de Nacimiento',
          'sexo': 'Sexo',
          'edad': 'Edad',
        }
        widgets = {
          'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
          'apellidoMaterno': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
          'apellidoPaterno ': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
          'TipoDeSangre ': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
          'FechaDeNacimiento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
          'sexo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
          'edad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

El del paciente_form es este:

```
{& extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

¿Cómo podría arreglar este detalle ? ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Comment: Imaginate que yo ahora te pregunto lo mismo y no te digo nada más que esto, podrías tu ayudarme?

Comment: ya lo corregi, es mi primera pregunta, apenas me voy acoplando

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el fallo lo tienes en la línea del `return`, que lo tienes dentro del `if request.method == 'POST':`.

Si sacas el `return` de ese `else`, siempre cargará el formulario, independientemente de si es `GET` o `POST`. En tu caso solo pasa por ese `return` cuando `request.method` es igual a `POST` y además el formulario no es válido.

```
def paciente_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = pacienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('paciente:index')
        else:
            # aquí gestiona lo que ocurre cuando el formulario no es válido
    else:
        form = pacienteForm() # aquí iniciamos un formulario vacío para que lo pinte cuando request.method sea distinto de POST
    return render(request, 'paciente/paciente_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Prueba esto a ver si es lo que buscas.

Comment: ME sigue marcando error. No se si tenga que ver pero al importar 

from django.http import  HttpResponse me sale una leyenda que dice "unused import statement". Esto en el archivo de views.py

Comment: `unused import statement` quiere decir que has importado algo que no estás utilizando, pero el programa debería correr sin problemas. Si no te pinta el formulario, quizá se deba a que en el template no lo estás pintando como es debido? Pon una muestra del template donde renderizas el formulario, así podremos seguir acotando el problema.

Comment: claro, deja agrego el template.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `{{form.as_p}}` por `{{ form }}` a ver si así te lo pinta..